# Javafx rotate Label issue

Tags: javafx-2

- I have an issue when i try to rotate the label by 270 `label.setRotate(270)`.
- But label text **disappear** .

[image: label text disappear]

- That is the code sample.

  ```
  LineChart chart = new LineChart(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());
  chart.setLegendVisible(false); 

  /**
   * Grid pane which contain the charts and vertical label to indicate for the row title
   */
  GridPane root = new GridPane();
  root.add(chart, 0, 0);

  /**
   * Want to add vertical label to refer to the row title.
   */
  Label label = new Label("Row Title");
  label.setRotate(270);
  // label.setMinWidth(200); 

  root.add(label, 1, 0);
  ```

**Update**

- When i try to `setMinWidth(200)` another issue appear.
  [image: Label still take it's width space after rotate]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that adding a rotation to the label doesn't affect its layout bounds.  The label is, as far as layout is concerned, still a horizontal control.

Wrapping it in a `Group` will solve most issues, as the group will take the transform into account.  However, things like automatic wrapping of text in the label will no longer function.

If text wrapping in a vertical label is also desired, then we need to create our own `VerticalLabel` class that re-uses the complex wrapping calculations done by `Label` while showing it vertically.

This feature should really be part of the `Label` class itself to be supported properly, but it is possible to work-around it with a new control.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.VerticalDirection;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.OverrunStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;

public class VerticalLabel extends Pane {
  private final InternalLabel label = new InternalLabel();
  private final VerticalDirection direction;

  public VerticalLabel(VerticalDirection direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
    this.label.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(direction == VerticalDirection.DOWN ? 90 : -90, 0, 0));
    this.label.setManaged(false);
    this.getChildren().add(label);
  }

  // Content bias is Vertical if text wrapping is active: 

  @Override
  public Orientation getContentBias() {
    return label.isWrapText() ? Orientation.VERTICAL : null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();

    label.resizeRelocate(direction == VerticalDirection.DOWN ? getWidth() : 0, direction == VerticalDirection.DOWN ? 0 : getHeight(), getHeight(), getWidth());
  }

  // Compute methods, with width and height swapped around:

  @Override
  protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
    return label.computePrefHeight(height);
  }

  @Override
  protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
    return label.computePrefWidth(width);
  }

  @Override
  protected double computeMaxWidth(double height) {
    return label.computeMaxHeight(height);
  }

  @Override
  protected double computeMaxHeight(double width) {
    return label.computeMaxWidth(width);
  }

  @Override
  protected double computeMinWidth(double height) {
    return label.computeMinHeight(height);
  }

  @Override
  protected double computeMinHeight(double width) {
    return label.computeMinWidth(width);
  }

  // Delegate methods:

  public ObjectProperty<Node> labelForProperty() {
    return label.labelForProperty();
  }

  public final StringProperty textProperty() {
    return label.textProperty();
  }

  public final String getText() {
    return label.getText();
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    label.setText(text);
  }

  public final void setLabelFor(Node value) {
    label.setLabelFor(value);
  }

  public final Node getLabelFor() {
    return label.getLabelFor();
  }

  public final ObjectProperty<TextAlignment> textAlignmentProperty() {
    return label.textAlignmentProperty();
  }

  public final void setTextAlignment(TextAlignment value) {
    label.setTextAlignment(value);
  }

  public final TextAlignment getTextAlignment() {
    return label.getTextAlignment();
  }

  public final ObjectProperty<OverrunStyle> textOverrunProperty() {
    return label.textOverrunProperty();
  }

  public final void setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle value) {
    label.setTextOverrun(value);
  }

  public final OverrunStyle getTextOverrun() {
    return label.getTextOverrun();
  }

  public final StringProperty ellipsisStringProperty() {
    return label.ellipsisStringProperty();
  }

  public final void setEllipsisString(String value) {
    label.setEllipsisString(value);
  }

  public final String getEllipsisString() {
    return label.getEllipsisString();
  }

  public final BooleanProperty wrapTextProperty() {
    return label.wrapTextProperty();
  }

  public final boolean isWrapText() {
    return label.isWrapText();
  }

  public void setWrapText(boolean wrapText) {
    label.setWrapText(wrapText);
  }

  public final ObjectProperty<Font> fontProperty() {
    return label.fontProperty();
  }

  public final void setFont(Font value) {
    label.setFont(value);
  }

  public final Font getFont() {
    return label.getFont();
  }

  public final ObjectProperty<Node> graphicProperty() {
    return label.graphicProperty();
  }

  public final void setGraphic(Node value) {
    label.setGraphic(value);
  }

  public final Node getGraphic() {
    return label.getGraphic();
  }

  public final ObjectProperty<ContextMenu> contextMenuProperty() {
    return label.contextMenuProperty();
  }

  public final void setContextMenu(ContextMenu value) {
    label.setContextMenu(value);
  }

  public final BooleanProperty underlineProperty() {
    return label.underlineProperty();
  }

  public final void setUnderline(boolean value) {
    label.setUnderline(value);
  }

  public final DoubleProperty lineSpacingProperty() {
    return label.lineSpacingProperty();
  }

  public final void setLineSpacing(double value) {
    label.setLineSpacing(value);
  }

  public final double getLineSpacing() {
    return label.getLineSpacing();
  }

  public final ObjectProperty<ContentDisplay> contentDisplayProperty() {
    return label.contentDisplayProperty();
  }

  public final void setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay value) {
    label.setContentDisplay(value);
  }

  public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Insets> labelPaddingProperty() {
    return label.labelPaddingProperty();
  }

  public final Insets getLabelPadding() {
    return label.getLabelPadding();
  }

  public final DoubleProperty graphicTextGapProperty() {
    return label.graphicTextGapProperty();
  }

  public final void setGraphicTextGap(double value) {
    label.setGraphicTextGap(value);
  }

  public final double getGraphicTextGap() {
    return label.getGraphicTextGap();
  }

  public final void setTextFill(Paint value) {
    label.setTextFill(value);
  }

  public final Paint getTextFill() {
    return label.getTextFill();
  }

  public final ObjectProperty<Paint> textFillProperty() {
    return label.textFillProperty();
  }

  public final BooleanProperty mnemonicParsingProperty() {
    return label.mnemonicParsingProperty();
  }

  /**
   * Inner class to make compute(...) methods accessible.
   */
  private class InternalLabel extends Label {
    @Override
    public double computePrefWidth(double height) {
      return super.computePrefWidth(height);
    }

    @Override
    public double computePrefHeight(double width) {
      return super.computePrefHeight(width);
    }

    @Override
    public double computeMaxWidth(double height) {
      return super.computeMaxWidth(height);
    }

    @Override
    public double computeMaxHeight(double width) {
      return super.computeMaxHeight(width);
    }

    @Override
    public double computeMinWidth(double height) {
      return super.computeMinWidth(height);
    }

    @Override
    public double computeMinHeight(double width) {
      return super.computeMinHeight(width);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `...` text you are seeing is the default value of `ellipsisStringProperty` when the text is truncated due to narrow bounds. The `label.setMinWidth(200);` should solve of the issue of disappearance.

Comment: I already did that but another issue appear,kindly see question update.

Comment: I have got the same issue, it sets the width before rotating and therefore the white space appears. Is there a solution already?

Comment: @bashoogzaad currently don't have info for this problem. You may ask a new question about it because since then the framework is evolved.

Comment: @UlukBiy posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031565/rotating-label-90-degrees-takes-up-unnecessary-horizontal-space