# Java Fx : strange behaviour when trying to write a Label vertically

Tags: rotation, javafx, label, javafx-8, java-8

I have noticed a strange behaviour concerning rotated texts (Label,...) in JavaFx...

Originally, I just wanted to be able to display Labels vertically in a GridPane. The first problem is that there is no simple way to tell a Label to display its content in a given direction/orientation. It would be nice to have something like the Side property of the tabPane which would allow to easily turn the text around...

Anyway, I then resigned myself to use the Rotate function to turn my Label. That is when the strange thing began to occur...I am putting my Label in a grid cell which would not be large enough to display the full text if it is not rotated but the text should be able to fit once rotated. The problem is that the text appears wrapped even when it is rotated as if the wrapping test were done before the text is actually rotated... The problem can be seen on this screenshot http://hpics.li/e210f2f : the text that should be displayed is written in the Tooltip and we can see that only the first letter of the rotated text is displayed in the cell grid even though there is more than enough space to display it all...

Anyone has any idea on how to solve that ? Is it the intended behaviour or is it just a little bug ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Related  [Javafx rotate Label issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921495/javafx-rotate-label-issue).

Comment: I agree with Uluk Biy. Try playing with the minimum and maximum properties from Node. We usually set setMaxWidth (Double.MAX_VALUE) in certain layout panels, for example, when we want to lengthen something. This is immediately perceptible, for example, when using BorderPane.

Comment: Unfortunately, no matter how much I play with the MaxWidth parameter, nothing changes. It is as if the need to display the wrapping '...' were computed before the rotation while it should be done after...

Comment: Workaroud found by James_D : https://community.oracle.com/thread/3514254 .