# Rotating label 90 degrees takes up unnecessary horizontal space

Tags: javafx, rotation, label, javafx-8

This question is based on [Javafx rotate Label issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921495/javafx-rotate-label-issue), but because this post is outdated and has no satisfying answer, I would like to mention it again.

**The problem is:**

When rotating a label for 90 or 270 degrees, firstly the text is being truncated because it has not the right minimum width. When I set the minimum width, the text is not being truncated anymore.

However, the minimum width is also set in the horizontal direction, as shown below:

[image: Label issue with minimum width]

On the left is the situation as it is now in Java 8u40, and on the right is how I like it to be (and which is the most logical way in my opinion).

I have just used this code:

```
Label label = new Label("This is a label.");
label.setRotate(270);
label.setMinWidth(200);
```

I have added the label to a `AnchorPane`, which is not part of the problem I except. I also tried @James_D workaround (https://community.oracle.com/thread/3514254), which did not work for me either.

**So my question is:**

Is this a known bug, and if so: is there any chance it will be fixed in the future? Also, is there another workaround possible (apart from placing the label in an image)?

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain why wrapping the label in a group doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you only need text you can try to use the Text class instead of a Label control. Can you open an issue at OpenJFX? (https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa)

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. The [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) (read "Bounding Rectangles") clearly states that transforms are not included in the calculation of layout bounds. The [documentation for `Group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) states "if transforms and effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds". So wrapping a rotated label in a `Group` will work (and does for me). If it doesn't work, post some code showing that.

Comment: @James_D I was rotating the group instead of the label. Sorry, my bad! Maybe it is better to close this question..

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it´s a bug. I did a test with a JavaFX app with rotating text on Windows (running Oracle JavaFX, JDK1.8.0.60j and then I moved it to Raspberry Pi. The Pi was running Open JavaFX. In Open JavaFX the rotation is performed correctly, while the Oracle JavaFX shows the behaviour you decribed here.